# How to calculate 12 weeks back date in java?

Tags: java

I know I can get the current date using `new Date()`, but I want to get a past date (12 weeks back). For example: today is Jan 3rd 2014, a 12 weeks old date would be Oct 11 2013.

How to do that in java?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is the 'official' tutorial focused on 1.8.

Answer (score 10):

```
Date date = new Date();
long timeAgo = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 12;
Date dateAgo = new Date(date.getTime() - timeAgo);
```

Should work just fine. Don't miss the `L` from the  multiplication, otherwise you'll get overflow results. Good spot by [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo).

FYI, the timeAgo columns are as follows:

```
1000 is representative of a second (1000 milliseconds)
1000 * 60 is representative of a minute (60 seconds)
1000 * 60 * 60 is representative of an hour (60 minutes)
1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 is representative of a day (24 hours)
1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 is representative of a week (7 days)
1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 12 is representative of 12 weeks (12 weeks)
```

Comment: @Alex the above allows for more customisable situations. Plus, it explains the logic for calculating time which is useful to anyone.

Comment: @Alex then where would you learn anything? :)

Comment: Code should be abstract as much as possible.

Comment: @Alex Say he wants to then do it in some other language without the same libraries. How does he do it without knowing the logic behind it? Ask again based on that language? I agree, code should be to the point - but there is a time and place for that.

Comment: The question is about java only.

Comment: @Alex That's kinda my point. But anyway, under someone else's answer isn't the place to get offended that their answer got more upvotes than yours, so let's leave it there.

Comment: This approach is error-prone (and you showed it). Try printing `dateAgo` and you will be surprised with result. It is better to use build in methods to avoid surprises like [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: The problem with is approach is it to easy to trip over irregularities in date/time. Not every day is is exactly 24 hours long and leap years, century and millennium boundaries all add it additional considerations...

Comment: @Pshemo Valid point. And MadProgrammer that's also valid, but that might be the desired behaviour. For example, it works for this question (we need specifics to go further).

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. Your `timeAgo` will overflow to `-1332334592` so in reality by `-timeAgo` you are adding `1332334592` milliseconds to current date.

Comment: @Pshemo Oops, been using jscript too much and forgot about my ints. Fixed it now.

Comment: Dont use `l` to specify `long` (it looks more like `1`). Use `L` instead. Also try adding this suffix to your first operand `1000L` to make result of first multiplying (and by that also others) `long`. It helps making sure that you will not overflow integer before you will multiply it with last operand `12L`.

Answer (score 8):

Most of Date is actually deprecated, it has been superseded by [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -12);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [LocalDate.minusWeeks](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusWeeks-long-) of JDK 1.8,

```
 LocalDate first=LocalDate.now();
 LocalDate second=first.minusWeeks(12);
```

Comment: because everyone runs Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised no one mentioned [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) yet.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dt);
System.out.println(dt.minusWeeks(12));
System.out.println(dt.minusWeeks(12).toDate());//if you prefer Date object
```

Output:

```
2014-01-03T04:40:40.402+01:00
2013-10-11T04:40:40.402+02:00
Fri Oct 11 04:40:40 CEST 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateUtils.addWeeks(new Date(), -12);
```

More about [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html).